Binary combinations with special criteria
Let there be a binary value of "n" bits which consists of only "0"s and "1"s.
If we pick exactly "r" "1"s of them (and the rest "n-r" are "0"s), the formula for the total combinations count is -
c = n! / r! (n-r)!

For example -
n = 20 bits
r = 4 (pick exactly 4 "1"s out of the given 20 bits, the other bits are "0"s)
c = Total combinations count = 20! / 4! (20-4)! = 20! / 4! 16! = 4845

The above would be the total combinations count, where the "1"s could be adjacent or have less "0"s between them.

Now let us include a more complex scenario:
Let there be 4 values of 256 bits each (256*4 = 1024 bits), 
and each of them has exactly 1 set of "000000001" in them

Example (the "|" is used just for separation purpose) -
001000000001001001..256 bits..00101 | 011010100101..256 bits..0010101000000001 | 
000000001001010101..256 bits..00101 | 1101010000000010101..256 bits..000110101 

If we are to consider the "n choose r" approach in this case (where "r"=000000001, and we consider remaining bits as 0s for calculation purpose), it would become -
c = Total combinations count = 1024 choose 4 = 1024! / 4! (1024-4)!
But actually it would not be such a big number because -

there would be no overlapping "000000001" bits (i.e. they will be separated by at least 8 bits)
there would be only 1 "000000001" in a set of 256 bits

How can we consider the above factors to reduce the total combinations count?
Provided the count can be reduced, can we rank and unrank the combinations, as answered here -

Binary combinations - rank and unrank
Thanks.
